# Grails domain is mapped to an unwanted _IDX column

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails3

One of my Grails domains, 'Organisation' can't save in our database because it expects the table to contain a column 'ORGANISATION_IDX'. I however have other domains in the project, neither of them having this problem.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode // this is the only domain having this annotation, but commenting it doesn't solve the issue
class Organisation {
    SomeClass someClass

    SomeDomain someDomain

    // some additional String and Date fields

    static embedded = ['someClass']
    static hasOne = ['someDomain': SomeDomain]

    static constraints = {
        // some constaints for my fields    
    }

    static mapping = {
        table name: 'MY_DOMAIN', schema: 'MY_SCHEMA'
        datasource 'my_domains'

        id column 'DOMAIN_ID', generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'MY_SEQUENCE', schema: 'MY_SCHEMA']

        autoTimestamp true
        version false
    }
}
```

Why does it happen for this domain and not another? How can ensure that hibernate remove this expectation of having an 'ORGANISATION_IDX' column?

Comment: Can you show the relevant output from `schema-export`?

Comment: create table someClass (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, SOME_CLASS varchar(255), ZIP varchar(255), CITY varchar(255), primary key (id));

Comment: I don't see any mention of `ORGANISATION_IDX` in that DDL.

Comment: There seems to be a reference to _idx in the GrailsDomainBinder of gorm, but I don't know what causes this field to be added; https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5/src/main/groovy/org/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/GrailsDomainBinder.java

I sent everything that was in the schema-export output.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problematic behavior you are describing.

Comment: Thanks for you investigation.